# Python 2.7 NameError

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am trying to make code, that when button is pressed (uzdaryti porta), then the written port in text box is closed. The error I get is

> myg2 = Button(virsus, text="Uzdaryti porta", command=lambda: uzdaras())
>   NameError: free variable 'uzdaras' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Is it because I use the same text variable for both buttons?

```
def portas():
        root = Tk()
        root.title("Atidaryti/uzdaryti portus")
        root.geometry("300x100")
        tekstas = Text(root, height=1, width=15)
        tekstas.pack(side=TOP)
        virsus = Frame(root)
        virsus.pack()
        apacia = Frame(root)
        apacia.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        myg1 = Button(virsus, text="Atidaryti porta", command=lambda: atidaryti())
        myg2 = Button(virsus, text="Uzdaryti porta", command=lambda: uzdaras())
        myg1.pack(side=LEFT)
        myg2.pack(side=LEFT)
        def atidaryti():
         imti = tekstas.get("1.0", "end-1c")
         subprocess.call("echo linas123 | sudo -S ufw allow '{imti}'".format(imti=imti), shell=True)
        root.mainloop()

        def uzdaras():
         imti = tekstas.get("1.0", "end-1c")
         subprocess.call("echo linas123 | sudo -S ufw deny '{imti}'".format(imti=imti), shell=True)
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to define functions before you can use them, so just move your `uzdaras` function above where you call it

Comment: I did that, now the `uzdaras` button is gone and after the program is closed, it gives me this error `TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed`

Comment: Fix your **Indentation** .